# How to write Blob data into html in java

Tags: java, html, inputstream, outputstream

I have a html tag

```html
<td>
  <table style="padding-left:20px">
    <tr>
      <td align="middle"><img align="middle" src="{{LINK_FILE}}" style="margin-left: -7px; width:1px;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://example.com">Data Part<a></td>
    </table>
  </td>
```

The above {{LINK_FILE}} part I need to replace dynamically with a image present in the Oracle db as Blob. Then this final html needs to be sent as an email with the attached image.

Comment: Come up with something that you have tried

Comment: I am trying to replace the marker {{LINK_FILE}} with the inputstream that I got from the DB. But not working.

Comment: Add your code to the question that you have tried that will be easy to correct your mistake.

Comment: You should convert it to base64 and do something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried with that but the final html part does not show the image in outlook and also in gmail the src part is missing. Though in the final mail body it is present

Comment: I don't use either GMail or Outlook, but could it be that they're blocking images in general?